# Buffer.concat vs Buffer.copy in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have two cases on using node js `Buffer` in different place:

1. Buffer accumulation, which I have several buffers and will combine all of
   them together in the end.
2. Buffer writer, which I just need to resize the Buffer when it's
   insufficient anymore to hold more data.

Naturally, I will use `Buffer.concat` for the first case and `Buffer.copy` for
the second case. But, that can be reversed in which I can use `Buffer.copy` for
the first case and `Buffer.concat` for the second case.

Implementation 1 `Buffer.concat` for first case and `Buffer.copy` for second case:

```
// first case: buffer accumulation
const result = Buffer.concat([arrayOfBuffers])

// second case: buffer writer
if (oldbuffer.length - offset < newdata.length) {
  const newsize = oldbuffer.length * growthFactor + newdata.length
  const newbuffer = Buffer.alloc(newsize)
  oldbuffer.copy(newbuffer)
  newdata.copy(newbuffer, offset)
  result = newbuffer
}
// newbuffer is the end result
```

Implementation 2 `Buffer.copy` for second case and `Buffer.concat` for first case:

```
// first case: buffer accumulation
const totalSize = arrayOfBuffers.reduce((size, buff) => size + buff.length, 0)
const result = Buffer.alloc(totalSize)
let offset = 0
for (const buff of arrayOfBuffers) {
  buff.copy(result, offset)
  offset += buff.length
}

// second case: buffer writer
const result = Buffer.concat([oldbuffer, newdata])
```

I don't know how both `concat` and `copy` internally works in node js. So,
which method is best for both case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [implementation of `Buffer.concat`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/65fe999ed77c958468ca55c24e9242e193b55f95/lib/buffer.js#L448): It seems to be doing exactly what you suggested as replacement in implementation 2/first case: Create a new buffer with the calculated total length, then copy all buffers into the output.

So, based on that it seems reasonable to continue to use `Buffer.concat` directly, because the code is more concise, easier to follow, and describes better what you want to do ("concatenate all these buffers!")

For the writer case: Your suggested implementations aren't equivalent -- the first one would leave space at the end for adding new data, while the second implementation provides exactly the space needed for the existing buffers. If you need the extra space (optimization for expected future writes, for example), then stick to the first variant, otherwise the same argument applies: Using `concat` is more concise and easier to read.